# Is there a problem if I add a non-existing path to `PATH` environment variable?

Tags: directory, path, test

I have a following lines in my `.bash_profile`.

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

I think I found it somewhere in the internet.

Is it also ok, if I write only `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` without checking directory existence?
Does it cause a problem if I add a non-existing path to `$PATH`?

Comment: As @Anthon already answered there is not problem with adding non-existing paths, but `bash` will always complain if it doesn't find a given command, as usual. I don't see the point of the above test.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is easy to try this out. `bash` will not complain if you add a non-existing directory in PATH (but obviously it will not find any commands or scripts in there either).

If you later create the directory and store executables in there, `bash` will find them.

Answer (score 3):

Think about it another way, the only reason to check any following path in PATH is because there was an error finding a file at the previous one. So errors will cause no problem, in fact they are expected.